# (loop file by file and do something) with parallel program

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I have two folders: `src/` and `build/`.

In `src/assets/`, I have some files with same name in `build/`.

I would like to do something about those files in `src/assets/` with **parallel program**.

My single process version:

```sh
cd ../src/assets
find -type f -printf '%P\n' |
while read -r filename
do
    # no exist == very old
    if [[ "$filename" -nt ../../build/"$filename" ]]; then
        echo "$filename" # do something about $filename
    fi
done
```

How to turn this into parallel version?

Answer (score 0):

this is how i would do it:

```
cd ../src/assets
find -type f -printf '%p\n' |
  sed 's,.*,[[ "&" -nt ../../build/"&" ]] \&\& echo "&",' |
  parallel
```

this creates a bunch of commands of the form:

```
[[ "file1" -nt ../../build/"file1" ]] && echo "file1"
[[ "file2" -nt ../../build/"file2" ]] && echo "file2"
[[ "file3" -nt ../../build/"file3" ]] && echo "file3"
```

and then sends them to parallel to execute on several cores.

(requires GNU `parallel`)

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler solution:

```
cd ../src/assets || exit 1 
find . ../../build -type f -printf '%f\n' | sort | uniq -d | parallel echo
```